# NodeJS server run individual process for each request against queue

Tags: node.js, http, server

**See this example node.js code:**

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.url === '/loop') {
        console.log('LOOP');
        while (true) {}
    }
    res.write('Hello World');
    res.end();
});

server.listen(3000);
```

In my script each request takes 3 to 5 seconds to process. `while (true) {}` is just for example.

But, here nodejs not processing another request when one request in process.

I want to run multiple requests at same time. But, server is running only one request at one time.

**NOTE:** I don't like to open cluster or child_process for each request. Because nodejs takes another `65 ms` for starting cluster or child_process.

Comment: What exactly are you doing that takes 3-5 seconds? Reading/writing files? Requests to another server?

Comment: @Molda Some process with `fuse.js` for fuzzy text search. It takes that times for searching on more 10 million names. Also `fuse.js` completely sync process.

Answer (score 0):

When you create server ( and listens ) nodejs creates an eventloop in which it process the request, you will not be able to use a infinite loop in it, since it will block the eventloop in which your server is running.

I hope you are not dealing with an infinite loop, but a certain process that takes time, for that you make use of, modules like [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async)
in request/res function block use async module like this,

```
async.map(['param1','param2','param3'], task, function(err, results) {
    // results of task function
});
```

what it does is that it will make use of already running eventloop and run the process.

**Point to Note** :

1. Most Javascript VMs are single threaded ( including NodeJS ) hence you can also make use of `setTimeout` function instead of an infinite while loop
2. You will not be able to create a thread in NodeJS instead use any process based solution like cluster or childprocess ( single threaded VM )

Comment: But `async` module is not useful for sync processes. I'm running sync process for processing request.

Comment: by `sync` you meant the output may affect  the other clients ?

Comment: no no, other clients needs wait until existing process complete.

Comment: @ChandraNakka updated the answer with some details on JS vms, hope it helps you figure out the solution.